# Не листаются слайды baguetteBox.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html5, bootstrap

слайдер сделан с помощью baguetteBOX? Когда открываешь lightbox, не получается листать слайды.

```js
  baguetteBox.run('.tz-gallery', {
  captions: false, // display image captions.
  buttons: true, // arrows navigation  
  fullScreen: false,
  noScrollbars: false,
  bodyClass: 'baguetteBox-open',
  titleTag: false,
  async: false,
  preload: 2,
  animation: 'slideIn',
  verlayBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.8)'
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.css" />
 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
```

пример находится тут 
http://nanny-ekb.ru/organizatsiya-prazdnikov/detskij-razvivayushchij-centr/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: overlayBackgroundCol у вас опция не с ошибкой в имени

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не правильная структура html для того чтобы слайдер перелистывал картинки нужно в контейнере `tz-gallery` их было несколько а у вас в каждом только по одной.

```
<div class="tz-gallery">
   <div class="slick-image-slide">  
       <div class="slick-image-slide-wrap" style="height:300px;">
           <a href="http://nanny-ekb.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/LY7A9591.jpg" class="lightbox" tabindex="-1">
               <img src="http://nanny-ekb.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/LY7A9591.jpg" alt="ЛАГЕРЬ ФОТО 3">    
           </a>
       </div>                
   </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое ))